# Error retrieving data from Firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to sync my app to a firebase database to retrieve some data. With the code below, I'm able to console log 'polls' which is a basic collection I made in Firebase, and I can see all my data in the console log.

But if I actually try to reach into the polls object using polls.data.id or polls.data.label or even just polls.data, the page blanks out and I get an error saying that it "Cannot read the properties" that I'm calling for. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore"
import { db } from '../firebase.config'

function Food() {
  const [polls, setPolls] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    getPolls()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(polls.data.id);
  }, [polls])

  function getPolls() {
    const pollsRef = collection(db, 'polls');
    
    getDocs(pollsRef).then(response => {
      const poll = response.docs.map(doc => ({data: doc.data(), id: doc.id}))
      setPolls(poll)
    }).catch(error => console.log(error.message))
  }
 
  return (
    <div>
      Food
    </div>
  ) 
}

export default Food
```

Since my app is clearly fetching the object properly, I'm not sure why I'm not able to actually retrieve the data from within the object to use in my app.

[image: Error messages when I try to call for polls.data.id]

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Yes, I added the error screenshot for when I try to call for polls.data.id

When I just call for polls.data, I don't actually get errors, i just get "undefined" returned in the console log. Is it possible it's an async/await issue? Searching around, it seems like undefined gets returned when there is no document within firebase, so maybe it's not able to reference the document in time before loading the data?

Comment: Can you replace the screenshot with the actual text of the errors and stack trace? Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Your `polls` is an array, so you can't just `console.log(polls.data.id)`. Since `polls` is an array, it has no `data` attribute, and thus you can't call `id` on that, which is what the error says.

Instead, loop over the results with:

```
useEffect(() => {
  polls.forEach((pol) => 
    console.log(poll.id);
  })
}, [polls])
```

Note that I also `console.log(poll.id)`, since you map the ID to the object itself, not in its `data` property.